# Burpsuite - CSRF Token Macro

Tags: csrf, fuzzing, burp-suite

I implemented a website using the `vaadin-framework`. When I send a request to my server, there is some data in my `POST-Request` which looks like:

> `{"csrfToken":"3df2f528-15c7-434c-8505-539be1c44157","rpc":[["13","v","v",["text",["s","Nazar Medeiros"]]],["13","v","v",["c",["i",4]]],["15","com.vaadin.shared.ui.button.ButtonServerRpc","click",[{"altKey":false,"button":"LEFT","clientX":82,"clientY":286,"ctrlKey":false,"metaKey":false,"relativeX":45,"relativeY":18,"shiftKey":false,"type":1}]]],"syncId":3,"clientId":3}`

Now the interesting part for me are three parameters:

> `Nazar Medeiros`, `"syncId":3` and `"clientId":3"`.

The content (Response) I receive from the server looks like:

> `for(;;);[{"syncId": 4, "clientId": 4, "changes" :
>   [["change",{"pid":"13"},["1",{"id":"13"}]]],
>   "state":{"13":{"text":"Nazar Medeiros"}},
>   "types":{"13":"1","25":"19","26":"21","6":"20"},
>   "hierarchy":{"25":[],"26":[],"6":["7","10","11","12","25","26"]},
>   "rpc" :
>   [["25","com.vaadin.shared.data.DataProviderRpc","resetDataAndSize",[0]],["25","com.vaadin.shared.data.DataProviderRpc","setRowData",[0,[]]]],
>   "meta" : {}, "resources" : {}, "timings":[3306, 1]}]`

I want to use `burp suite` and a `macro` for an automatic fuzzing process. When I use another value instead of `Nazar Medeiros` I have to increase `clientId` and `syncId` by 1 for each request.

What I have done so far, is to configure a `macro` with the two parameters. But the problem is that using the macro gives me not the result I want.

> `for(;;);[{"syncId": 26, "resynchronize": true, "clientId:4"...`

The `syncId` is increased by 2 instead of 1 whereas the `clientId` remains at the same value.

One solution I used (without macros) was to send the three paramteres to the `Intruder`, set the payload option to `Pitchfork` and give each of them a payload. The payload for `syncId` and `clientId` is the same and contains numbers for increasing the values at each request. To use this approach you have to be sure that `clientId` and `syncId` start at 0 (refresh the page). Otherwise the numbers do not fit to the requests.

I would be very happy if some could give me a better solution.
Best regards,
Nazar Medeiros